# How to Hide Navigation bar back button title globally in xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

**I used this code in AppDelegate,**

```
UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment (new UIOffset (-100, -60), UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

But it position is changed to bottom. I have attached the result screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution1 : set Title Color instead of Title Position

```
UITextAttributes attribute = new UITextAttributes {TextColor = UIColor.Clear };
UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(attribute, UIControlState.Normal);
```

#### Solution2 : set horizontal offset only.

```
UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment (new UIOffset (-100, 0), UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Cole Xia. Its Working fine

Comment: When i use this code,UITextAttributes attribute = new UITextAttributes {TextColor = UIColor.Clear };
UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(attribute, UIControlState.Normal);  Backbutton title is hided but any text added in tool bar that also hided. How to fix this issue