# How to Change Navigation Bar Style in IOS Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have referred the below link to hide the navigation bar back button title globally and its working fine, But when I add any text to toolbar, the toolbar text also hidden. Can anyone give suggestion to fix this issue.

[How to Hide Navigation bar back button title globally in xamarin.ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545153/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-back-button-title-globally-in-xamarin-ios)

Here is my toolbar code:

```
ToolbarItem tbi = new ToolbarItem() { Text = "Text", Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary };
ToolbarItems.Add(tbi);
```

Comment: ToolBarItem tbi= new ToolbarItem() { Text = "Text", Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary }; this.ToolbarItems.Add(tbi);

Comment: That is not a very good way to hide the back button. It may be affecting your toolbar text. This is a better way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935929/xamarin-forms-getting-rid-of-back-button-in-nav-bar

Comment: @SteveChadbourne He just wants to hide the back button title not the back button .

Comment: Oh yes I see now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change or remove the back button text on Xamarin.Forms is with this code:

```
NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "");
```

Note you need to do this in the page *before* the page the back button appears on i.e. the calling page.

I tried this and your toolbar code worked correctly.

EDIT

You can also create a base page containing the hide toolbar button code and inherit all pages from that.

Here is the base page:

```
public class BasePage : ContentPage
{
    public BasePage ()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "");
    }
}
```

Then the inherited page looks like this

```
public partial class MainPage : BasePage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and if it is a XAML page ensure you change the page type

```
<pages:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:ScratchPad.Pages;assembly=ScratchPad"
             x:Class="ScratchPad.Pages.MainPage"
             Title="List Test">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Page Two" Command="{Binding PageTwoCommand}"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>

</pages:BasePage>
```

[image]

Comment: I want to hide the navigation bar back button title globally not a particular page.

Comment: Perhaps a base class then where you put the code above then inherit all pages from that.

Comment: I set in my base class like this, public void ShowMainPage() { MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage(this))  { BarBackgroundColor = Color.Blue, BarTextColor = Color.White }; NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "") } .. But it is not hide the back button title globally

Comment: how to change the back button color in xamarin forms ios navigation bar? please anyone give a solution.